# Debug javascript code in atom ide

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, ide, package

I ask if there is a solution or a package to install in atom so that I can debug javascript (when using node) in the IDE, like the one offered by Visual Studio Code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Nuclide](https://nuclide.io) – an atom package – enables debugging of a page running in Chrome inside Atom.

More infos in the [Nuclide docs](https://nuclide.io/docs/features/debugger/).

Comment: Thank you , I just want to ask if it is used to debug node js because whenever I want to use the debugger it notices that there are no debugger attached?

Comment: If you want to attach a debugger, you're going to need to start a node process for the atom debugger to hook into via [`node --inspect`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).  By default, that runs on port 9229. The attached debugger allows you to interactively walk through whatever you run in the node terminal or IDE debugger console. I find it more convenient to use the IDE's `launch debugger` option to walk through a file.

Comment: Also, [Nuclide is now atom-ide-ui](https://nuclide.io/blog/2017/09/12/Introducing-Atom-IDE-UI/), so you'd install the ide via `apm install atom-ide atom-ide-debugger-node`.

Comment: @StevenKalt That's not strictly true, is it? `atom-ide-ui` is just a subset of Nuclide, and did not include a debugger when released: "Our hope is that other Nuclide features will eventually also become part of the Atom IDE effort, including key components like the Nuclide debugger."

Comment: For this purpose they're equivalent: the debugger was included in atom-ide-ui@0.10.1.  The nuclide task runner, mercurial support, working sets, and remote development capabilities don't look like they're getting ported.

Comment: This answer is quite out of date. And while technicall atom-ide-ui and atom-ide-debugger-node do allow for debugging javascript it's a pretty subpar user experience. Any updates on how to do this?